# SSIS Packet multiple tables from ms Access in to multiple tables on SQL

Tags: ssis

I have an access file mdb with 3 tables name 'table1, table 2 and table3'.
On SQL server, I have 3 tables and same name above and both identical fields name and type.
I can create ssis packet to import data **each table** from mdb into sql.
My goal to create one packet to **import data for all 3 tables in to SQL as the same time**.
I'm new to SSIS and need your help. 
Thank you.

Comment: Assuming you have 3 packages, just copy and paste the dataflows from two of the others into one.

Comment: Control flow or Data flow?

Comment: Copy the data flows into one of the other control flows